# Flex Weblogic Blazeds Error

Tags: apache-flex, weblogic, blazeds

I have Flex/Parsley/Blazeds application deployed on weblogic 9.x. The following error appears in the weblogic logs the very first time I try connect to server side java class using remoting. After the first time the application works fine...bizzarre any ideas would be appreacited thanks.

```
   FaultEvent fault=[RPC Fault faultString="Send failed" faultCode="Client.Error.MessageSend" faultDetail="Channel.Connect.Failed error NetConnection.Call.Failed: HTTP: Status 500: url: 'http://localhost:8001/ReviewItemsServer/messagebroker/amf'"] messageId="EA02DD33-22C2-A669-EB0C-EE377DBBC233" type="fault" bubbles=false cancelable=true eventPhase=2]
```

The weblogic logs show the following error:

```
<27-Oct-2010 13:22:45 o'clock BST> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101017> <[weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext@227c0a6 - appName: 'ReviewItemsServer', name: 'ReviewItemsServer.war', context-path: '/ReviewItemsServer'] Root cause of ServletException.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: setExclusiveOwnerThread
at edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync.lock(ReentrantLock.java:186)
at flex.messaging.HttpFlexSession.setHttpSession(HttpFlexSession.java:550)
```

I have included the WEB.XML for reference:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
        xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
                            http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" version="2.4">
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value> 
    /WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml,
    /WEB-INF/spring/infrastructureContext.xml
    </param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>flex.messaging.HttpFlexSession</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>flexspring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>flexspring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/messagebroker/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The weblogic console startup is shown below:

```
[Flex]Using MBeanServerLocator: flex.management.PlatformMBeanServerLocator
[Flex]No login command was found for 'WebLogic Server 9.2 Fri Jun 23 20:47:26 EDT 2006 783464 '. Please ensure that the login-command tag has the correct server attribute value, or use 'all' to use the login command regardless of the server.
[Flex]Endpoint 'my-streaming-amf' created with security: None
at URL: http://{server.name}:{server.port}/{context.root}/messagebroker/streamingamf
[Flex]Endpoint 'my-amf' created with security: None
at URL: http://{server.name}:{server.port}/{context.root}/messagebroker/amf
[Flex]Endpoint 'my-polling-amf' created with security: None
at URL: http://{server.name}:{server.port}/{context.root}/messagebroker/amfpolling
[Flex]MessageBroker id: _messageBroker classLoader is: the MessageBroker's class loader and the context class loader (classLoader hashCode: 61418221 (parent hashCode: 61416508 (parent hashCode: 61416374 (parent hashCode: 44613654 (parent hashCode: 36679827 (parent system)))))
[Flex]Service with id 'authentication-service' is starting.
[Flex]Service with id 'authentication-service' is ready (startup time: '0' ms)
[Flex]Service with id 'message-service' is starting.
[Flex]Service with id 'message-service' is ready (startup time: '0' ms)
[Flex]Service with id 'remoting-service' is starting.
[Flex]Service with id 'remoting-service' is ready (startup time: '0' ms)
```

Flex Debug - turned on - WITH INITIAL REMOTING ERROR

```
    Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.5.0_04-b05)
BEA JRockit(R) (build R26.0.0-189_CR269406-59389-1.5.0_04-20060322-1120-win-ia32, )
Starting WLS with line:
C:\bea\JROCKI~2\bin\java  -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=1044,server=y,suspend=n  -jrockit   -Xms256m -Xmx512m  -Xverify:none  -da -Dplatform.home=C:\bea\weblogic\9.2 -Dwls.home=C:\bea\weblogic\9.2\server -Dwli.home=C:\bea\weblogic\9.2\integration  -Dweblogic.management.disc
over=true  -Dwlw.iterativeDev= -Dwlw.testConsole= -Dwlw.logErrorsToConsole= -Dweblogic.ext.dirs=C:\bea\patch_weblogic920\profiles\default\sysext_manifest_classpath -Dweblogic.Name=AdminServer -Djava.security.policy=C:\bea\weblogic\9.2\server\lib\weblogic.policy   weblogic.Server
<14-Dec-2010 14:53:26 o'clock GMT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000395> <Following extensions directory contents added to the end of the classpath:
C:\bea\weblogic\9.2\platform\lib\p13n\p13n-schemas.jar;C:\bea\weblogic\9.2\platform\lib\p13n\p13n_common.jar;C:\bea\weblogic\9.2\platform\lib\p13n\p13n_system.jar;C:\bea\weblogic\9.2\platform\lib\wlp\netuix_common.jar;C:\bea\weblogic\9.2\platform\lib\wlp\netuix_schemas.jar;C:\bea\weblogic\9.2\platfo
rm\lib\wlp\netuix_system.jar;C:\bea\weblogic\9.2\platform\lib\wlp\wsrp-common.jar>
<14-Dec-2010 14:53:26 o'clock GMT> <Info> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000377> <Starting WebLogic Server with BEA JRockit(R) Version R26.0.0-189_CR269406-59389-1.5.0_04-20060322-1120-win-ia32 from BEA Systems, Inc.>
<14-Dec-2010 14:53:27 o'clock GMT> <Info> <Management> <BEA-141107> <Version: WebLogic Server 9.2  Fri Jun 23 20:47:26 EDT 2006 783464 >
<14-Dec-2010 14:53:28 o'clock GMT> <Info> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000215> <Loaded License : C:\bea\license.bea>
<14-Dec-2010 14:53:28 o'clock GMT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to STARTING>
<14-Dec-2010 14:53:28 o'clock GMT> <Info> <WorkManager> <BEA-002900> <Initializing self-tuning thread pool>
<14-Dec-2010 14:53:28 o'clock GMT> <Notice> <Log Management> <BEA-170019> <The server log file C:\bea\user_projects_91\domains\base_domain\servers\AdminServer\logs\AdminServer.log is opened. All server side log events will be written to this file.>
<14-Dec-2010 14:53:29 o'clock GMT> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090082> <Security initializing using security realm myrealm.>
<14-Dec-2010 14:53:31 o'clock GMT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to STANDBY>
<14-Dec-2010 14:53:31 o'clock GMT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to STARTING>
<14-Dec-2010 14:53:32 o'clock GMT> <Warning> <JMS> <BEA-040456> <An entity of type "ForeignServers" with name "SMO JMS Server" in JMS module "SMO_MODULE" is not targeted. There is no sub-deployment with name "SMO-Subdeployment" in the configuration repository (config.xml), and so this entity will no
t exist anywhere in the domain.>
[Flex]The class loader could not locate the string resource property file 'flex/messaging/errors_en_GB.properties'. This may not be an issue if a property file is available for a less specific locale or the default locale.
[Flex]The class loader could not locate the string resource property file 'flex/data/errors_en_GB.properties'. This may not be an issue if a property file is available for a less specific locale or the default locale.
[Flex]The class loader could not locate the string resource property file 'flex/messaging/errors_en.properties'. This may not be an issue if a property file is available for a less specific locale or the default locale.
[Flex]Not using MBeanServerLocator: flex.management.WebSphereMBeanServerLocator. Reason: Cannot create class of type 'com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminServiceFactory'.
[Flex]Using MBeanServerLocator: flex.management.PlatformMBeanServerLocator
[Flex]No login command was found for 'WebLogic Server 9.2 Fri Jun 23 20:47:26 EDT 2006 783464 '. Please ensure that the login-command tag has the correct server attribute value, or use 'all' to use the login command regardless of the server.
[Flex]Endpoint 'my-streaming-amf' created with security: None
at URL: http://{server.name}:{server.port}/{context.root}/messagebroker/streamingamf
[Flex]Endpoint 'my-amf' created with security: None
at URL: http://{server.name}:{server.port}/{context.root}/messagebroker/amf
[Flex]Endpoint 'my-polling-amf' created with security: None
at URL: http://{server.name}:{server.port}/{context.root}/messagebroker/amfpolling
[Flex]MessageBroker id: _messageBroker classLoader is: the MessageBroker's class loader and the context class loader (classLoader hashCode: 62652490 (parent hashCode: 62650777 (parent hashCode: 62650643 (parent hashCode: 44614166 (parent hashCode: 36679827 (parent system)))))
[Flex]Service with id 'authentication-service' is starting.
[Flex]Service with id 'authentication-service' is ready (startup time: '0' ms)
[Flex]Service with id 'message-service' is starting.
[Flex]Service with id 'message-service' is ready (startup time: '16' ms)
[Flex]Service with id 'remoting-service' is starting.
[Flex]Service with id 'remoting-service' is ready (startup time: '0' ms)
<14-Dec-2010 14:53:37 o'clock GMT> <Notice> <Log Management> <BEA-170027> <The server initialized the domain log broadcaster successfully. Log messages will now be broadcasted to the domain log.>
<14-Dec-2010 14:53:37 o'clock GMT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to ADMIN>
<14-Dec-2010 14:53:37 o'clock GMT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to RESUMING>
<14-Dec-2010 14:53:37 o'clock GMT> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[1]" is now listening on 127.0.0.1:8001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, http.>
<14-Dec-2010 14:53:37 o'clock GMT> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default" is now listening on 147.201.146.91:8001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, http.>
<14-Dec-2010 14:53:37 o'clock GMT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000331> <Started WebLogic Admin Server "AdminServer" for domain "base_domain" running in Development Mode>
<14-Dec-2010 14:53:37 o'clock GMT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to RUNNING>
<14-Dec-2010 14:53:37 o'clock GMT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000360> <Server started in RUNNING mode>
2010-12-14 14:53:38,593INFO org.apache.beehive.netui.util.config.parser.NetUIConfigParser   [Loading the default NetUI config file.  The runtime will be configured with a set of minimum parameters.]
2010-12-14 14:53:38,593INFO org.apache.beehive.netui.util.config.parser.NetUIConfigParser   [NetUIConfigParser -- load config: org/apache/beehive/netui/util/config/internal/beehive-netui-config-default.xml]
2010-12-14 14:53:38,640INFO org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.internal.AdapterManager   [No ServletContainerAdapter specified or discovered; using class org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.DefaultServletContainerAdapter]
2010-12-14 14:53:38,671INFO org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.ProcessPopulate   [Register RequestParameterHandler with
    prefix: checkbox_key
    handler: org.apache.beehive.netui.tags.html.CheckBox$CheckBoxPrefixHandler]
2010-12-14 14:53:38,671INFO org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.ProcessPopulate   [Register RequestParameterHandler with
    prefix: checkbox_group_key
    handler: org.apache.beehive.netui.tags.html.CheckBoxGroup$CheckboxGroupPrefixHandler]
2010-12-14 14:53:38,671INFO org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.ProcessPopulate   [Register RequestParameterHandler with
    prefix: radio_button_group_key
    handler: org.apache.beehive.netui.tags.html.RadioButtonGroup$RadioButtonGroupPrefixHandler]
2010-12-14 14:53:38,671INFO org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.ProcessPopulate   [Register RequestParameterHandler with
    prefix: select_key
    handler: org.apache.beehive.netui.tags.html.Select$SelectPrefixHandler]
2010-12-14 14:53:38,686INFO org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.internal.DefaultURLTemplatesFactory   [Running without URL template descriptor, /WEB-INF/beehive-url-template-config.xml]
2010-12-14 14:53:38,718DEBUGorg.apache.struts.util.PropertyMessageResources   [Initializing, config='org.apache.struts.action.ActionResources', returnNull=true]
2010-12-14 14:53:38,733DEBUGorg.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet   [Scanning web.xml for controller servlet mapping]
2010-12-14 14:53:38,749DEBUGorg.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet   [Process servletName=action, urlPattern=*.do]
2010-12-14 14:53:38,749DEBUGorg.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet   [Process servletName=XmlHttpRequestServlet, urlPattern=*.xhr]
2010-12-14 14:53:38,749DEBUGorg.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet   [Process servletName=XmlHttpRequestServlet, urlPattern=*.render]
2010-12-14 14:53:38,749DEBUGorg.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet   [Mapping for servlet 'action' = '*.do']
2010-12-14 14:53:38,765DEBUGorg.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.AutoRegisterActionServlet   [Initializing module path '' configuration from '/WEB-INF/classes/_pageflow/struts-config.xml']
2010-12-14 14:53:38,890DEBUGorg.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet   [Initializing module path '' message resources from 'org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.validation.defaultMessages']
2010-12-14 14:53:38,890DEBUGorg.apache.struts.util.PropertyMessageResources   [Initializing, config='org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.validation.defaultMessages', returnNull=true]
2010-12-14 14:53:38,890DEBUGorg.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet   [Initializing module path '' data sources]
2010-12-14 14:53:38,890DEBUGorg.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet   [Initializing module path '' plug ins]
<14-Dec-2010 14:53:56 o'clock GMT> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101017> <[weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext@3a979c2 - appName: 'ReviewItemsServer', name: 'ReviewItemsServer.war', context-path: '/ReviewItemsServer'] Root cause of ServletException.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: setExclusiveOwnerThread
    at edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync.lock(ReentrantLock.java:186)
    at edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lock(ReentrantLock.java:266)
    at edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Segment.put(ConcurrentHashMap.java:418)
    at edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.put(ConcurrentHashMap.java:884)
    at flex.messaging.HttpFlexSession.setHttpSessio (HttpFlexSession.java:550)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
```

Flex Debug - turned on - WITH SUCCESSFUL REMOTING CALL

```
    [Flex]Deserializing AMF/HTTP request
Version: 3
  (Message #0 targetURI=null, responseURI=/1)
    (Array #0)
      [0] = (Typed Object #0 'flex.messaging.messages.CommandMessage')
    operation = 5
    correlationId = ""
    headers = (Object #1)
      DSId = "nil"
      DSMessagingVersion = 1
    timestamp = 0
    body = (Object #2)
    clientId = null
    destination = ""
    messageId = "47D7323A-E6FC-AEC4-5584-E55FAF2E778F"
    timeToLive = 0

[Flex]FlexClient created with id '9BFE9C7A-4A0A-0B0A-1764-5544D742138B'.
[Flex]Executed command: (default service)
  commandMessage: Flex Message (flex.messaging.messages.CommandMessage)
    operation = client_ping
    clientId = 9BFE9C7A-4A1B-4999-ED3D-4866B9919E89
    correlationId =
    destination =
    messageId = 47D7323A-E6FC-AEC4-5584-E55FAF2E778F
    timestamp = 1292338442249
    timeToLive = 0
    body = {}
    hdr(DSEndpoint) = my-amf
    hdr(DSId) = nil
    hdr(DSMessagingVersion) = 1
  replyMessage: Flex Message (flex.messaging.messages.AcknowledgeMessage)
    clientId = 9BFE9C7A-4A1B-4999-ED3D-4866B9919E89
    correlationId = 47D7323A-E6FC-AEC4-5584-E55FAF2E778F
    destination = null
    messageId = 9BFE9CED-090E-DFC5-54A6-1F968D5CB445
    timestamp = 1292338442265
    timeToLive = 0
    body = null
    hdr(DSId) = 9BFE9C7A-4A0A-0B0A-1764-5544D742138B
    hdr(DSMessagingVersion) = 1.0

[Flex]Serializing AMF/HTTP response
Version: 3
  (Message #0 targetURI=/1/onResult, responseURI=)
    (Externalizable Object #0 'DSK')
      (Object #1)
    DSId = "9BFE9C7A-4A0A-0B0A-1764-5544D742138B"
    DSMessagingVersion = 1.0
1.292338442265E12
(Byte Array #2, Length 16)
(Byte Array #3, Length 16)
(Byte Array #4, Length 16)

[Flex]Deserializing AMF/HTTP request
Version: 3
  (Message #0 targetURI=null, responseURI=/2)
    (Array #0)
      [0] = (Typed Object #0 'flex.messaging.messages.RemotingMessage')
    operation = "setReviewItemsParams"
    source = null
    headers = (Object #1)
      DSRemoteCredentials = ""
      DSEndpoint = null
      DSRemoteCredentialsCharset = null
      DSId = "9BFE9C7A-4A0A-0B0A-1764-5544D742138B"
    timestamp = 0
    body = (Array #2)
      [0] = 11162
      [1] = 2
    clientId = null
    destination = "remoteReviewItemsService"
    messageId = "9E33D197-6D2A-7507-DBCA-E55FAEFFC8AB"
    timeToLive = 0

[Flex]Before invoke service: remoting-service
  incomingMessage: Flex Message (flex.messaging.messages.RemotingMessage)
    operation = setReviewItemsParams
    clientId = 9BFEA163-9D0F-10F2-D003-4609CD6AE1AA
    destination = remoteReviewItemsService
    messageId = 9E33D197-6D2A-7507-DBCA-E55FAEFFC8AB
    timestamp = 1292338442733
    timeToLive = 0
    body =
    [
      11162,
      2
    ]
    hdr(DSEndpoint) = my-amf
    hdr(DSId) = 9BFE9C7A-4A0A-0B0A-1764-5544D742138B
    hdr(DSRemoteCredentials) =

[Flex]Adapter 'java-object' called 'null.setReviewItemsParams(java.util.Arrays$ArrayList (Collection size:2)
  [0] = 11162
  [1] = 2
)'
[Flex]Result: 'null'
[Flex]After invoke service: remoting-service
  reply: null

[Flex]Serializing AMF/HTTP response
Version: 3
  (Message #0 targetURI=/2/onResult, responseURI=)
    (Externalizable Object #0 'DSK')
      1.292338442874E12
(Byte Array #1, Length 16)
(Byte Array #2, Length 16)
(Byte Array #3, Length 16)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are calling a method that either doesn't exist or you are calling it with non-matching parameters.

Comment: Hi James, the error appears to be within HttpFlexSession. As stated the very, very first time the remote call is made (to a java class) I get this error. All subsequent calls to the same remote method work just fine. The problems seem to be related to the very first time a HttpFlexSession is created.

Comment: Is the servlet being loaded on startup?  Do you have the HttpFlexSession listener in the web.xml?

Comment: James, I dont think the Flex/Spring servlet is being loaded on startup...I have included my Web.XML and Weblogic console output(above as reference)...If the servlet was being loaded shouldn't we see something like "Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'flexspring'" ?

Comment: That all looks correct.  The servlet is being loaded on startup and you have the right listener.  What versions of Spring BlazeDS and BlazeDS are you using?

Comment: I am using all the dependencies from your Flex 4 & Spring 3 Integration - Dzone RefCarz actually, so the versions are: Spring BlazeDS Integration 1.0.3, Spring Framework 3.0.2, BlazeDS 4

Comment: Hmmm...  Ok.  I've never tried it on Weblogic but it should just work.  Can you increase the logging verbosity to debug in the services-config.xml file?

Comment: Well I have used JBOSS with this application and works fine - so it could possibly be Weblogic related. I have included the DEBUG output above - under the sections "Flex Debug - turned on - WITH INITIAL REMOTING ERROR" and "Flex Debug - turned on - WITH SUCCESSFUL REMOTING CALL"

Comment: Hi James, any followup...the error is still there at startup. I'm thinking that it might be an error with the Spring/BlazeDS package deployed on Weblogic. To isolate the error I am thinking of removing Spring/BlazeDS and just going with BlazeDS. What are your thoughts on this? The source of the error is in -  flex.messaging.HttpFlexSession.setHttpSession - which should be standard in BlazeDS and Spring/BlazeDS right? So I'm thinking it could be a config issue on my side...

Answer (score 1):

You can check `backport-util-concurrent.jar` which must match your JDK.